# DSA Problems on LeetCode and GFG

Tags: compiler-errors, sum, time-complexity, runtime-error

Whenever I try to run my code on coding platforms such as Leetcode and GFG, they always show some error, maybe runtime errors or compile-time error but when the same code I write on VS Code or any other online compiler then, the code is executed properly and it's not that I don't take the general case, I try to keep my code very optimized.

Like, here in this code :-

```
int subarraySum(vector<int>& nums, int k) 
{
    int sum=0;
    int l=sizeof(nums);
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<l;j++)
        {
            int sum=0;
            for(int k=i;k<=j;k++)
            {
                sum+=nums[k];
            }
            if(k==sum)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This code is of Subarray sum equals to k. This code is running on vs code and giving the right results but on leetcode it is showing runtime error. So, I want to know why is this happening ?

Comment: Removed `dsa` tag: has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have used 'k' as loop variable, although it is received in function parameters as well. Just use different variable for the innermost loop.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that `sizeof` does not return the number of elements in the vector, but returns the number of memory bytes occupied by that array. That is a greater number. So your loop will access elements in that vector that are not in its range leading to undefined behaviour.

Correct this as follows: `int l=nums.size();`

With this correction the error will no longer occur.

Still, for this particular challenge you will probably run into a *"time limit exceeded"* error, because this algorithm is not efficient enough. Finding an efficient algorithm is the essence of the this challenge, which is out of scope for the question you asked, so I will not spoil the fun.